# Display registration errors from php array into modal

Tags: javascript, php, session, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make a registration form using bootstrap and PHP and post the errors in a modal. (Incorrent password/Invalid email address etc.) All error is put into an array. My problem is that I don't know how to take the array and use it in the HTML, and call the modal from there. Also, I don't want the page to refresh after I click on the "register button".

I've already tried from the below links but without success.
 [Button click not firing in modal window (Bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455906/button-click-not-firing-in-modal-window-bootstrap)
 [How to open the modal if there is a validation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843489/how-to-open-the-modal-if-there-is-a-validation-error)

This is the form from the file Register_login.php

**Register_login.php**

```
<div class="container form_container_register w-100 mt-1">
    <form method="post" action="Register_login_route.php" data-toggle="modal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmailRegister">Email adress</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmailRegister" name="inputEmailRegister" aria-descridedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPasswordRegister">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordRegister" name="inputPasswordRegister" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rePasswordRegister">Retype password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="rePasswordRegister" name="rePasswordRegister" placeholder="Retype password">
        </div>

        <div class="container register_buttons_container w-100 justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex">
            <button type="submit" name="reg_button" id="reg_button_id" value="Register" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" class="register_btn btn w-50">Register</button>  
        </div> 
    </form>
</div>
```

and the modal from the boostrap page: (is this the correct place to put it)?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Register_login_route.php**
$errors is the array where I store the error messages. I posted only what I do with that array. How can I use the session variable in the first PHP file? There is no problem with the PHP code. $session_start() is placed in both files, the problem is with displaying the modal

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $insertPass = md5($password);

    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO physical_users (email, password) VALUES (:email,:password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($insertQuery);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $insertPass);

    $result = $stmt->execute();

} else{
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
    header("location: Register_login.php");
}
```

I tried the solutions from the links above with the js but no success

Comment: Hey @Dharman thank for the advice, I'll check it out and make the adjustments after I solve the problem with the modal. I struggle with this for some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery AJAX to send a request with form data to your back end function and do the validation, return errors from there. Then you can print them out in your success function. In that case you won't need a form tag since it automatically refreshes the page. Just take the values of your inputs and send them in your AJAX call in the `data` field.
Example of an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "your_php_file_name.php",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {action:"myAction",email:someEmail,password:somePassword},
   success: function(res){

    console.log(res);

   }
})
```

And your PHP code should look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
   if($_POST["action"] == "myAction"){
     $email = $_POST["email"];
     $password = $_POST["password"];
     // Example of validation
     if(strlen($password) < 6){

       print "Password too short";

       // Printing anything will return the printed value to the success function of your AJAX call and you can work with it. If you want to return an array instead of a string you can do `print(json_encode($array))`

     }

   }
}
```

To call your modal you just need to write `$('#myModal').modal()` inside of your success function and display your errors in it. Hope this was helpful. If you have any questions leave a comment.

Comment: Your comment took me to the right direction, I used ajax and found some examples so thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Get the errors on the page. You can do this by printing it as a JavaScript variable on the page. Something like `

```
<script>var errorList = <?php echo json_encode($errors);>?; </script>`
```

2.) On the page, using JavaScript, check the errorList variable. If it has stuff in it, then invoke the bootstrap modal and show them. Something like

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if(errorList.length > 0){
      //Put the errors in the .modal-content element
      $("#exampleModalCenter .modal-content").text(errorList.join(","));
      //Show the modal
      $("#exampleModalCenter").modal("show");
    }
  })
</script>
```

that's a rough draft--spat out as i wrote this--but it should set you on the right path.